# Magento 2 Decline message disappears quickly

Tags: magento2, checkout

Magento 2 Decline message disappears quickly in the Checkout page when placing the order using a credit card.

```
/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this seems to be a known issue and was affecting me as well (on Magento 2.2.5). There is a fix [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2916#issuecomment-345343749) which seems to work (message remains visible for longer) only that it scrolls up for the first error only. It does not scroll up for consecutive errors.