# Magento 2.4 decline message disappears quickly - several quick fixes don't to the trick

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a problem on my updated Magento 2.4 store. The error messages (like insufficient stock amount) disappear after a short time. Instead, I want them to be visible until the customer clicks on them. This should be standard behaviour in my opinion for error messages!

I checked [the issue here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233259/magento-2-decline-message-disappears-quickly), but the [fix here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2916#issuecomment-345343749) did not work / the file is now different on Magento 2.4.

The overrides for `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html` did not work ([source](https://joeking.us/magento2/keep-checkout-error-messages-from-disappearing)). I have changed the file from

> div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages"
> data-bind="visible: isVisible(), click: removeAll"

to

> div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages" data-bind="click: removeAll">

Also, I did the suggested override for `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`: I changed the values for the timeout

> ```
> return Component.extend({
>     defaults: {
>         template: 'Magento_Ui/messages',
>         selector: '[data-role=checkout-messages]',
>         isHidden: false,
>         hideTimeout: 30000,
>         hideSpeed: 10000,
>         listens: {
>             isHidden: 'onHiddenChange'
>         }
>     },
> ```

I did the required `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and double checked every edit. Still, whenever there is an alert message, it disappears after a very short period of time. The annoying thing is, that it is not about styling or visibility, the whole message just disappears from the code.

For every success message, the structure is like this:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'"> 
<!-- ko if: cookieMessages &&
cookieMessages.length > 0 --> 
<div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: {
data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages"> <div
data-bind="attr: { class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' +
message.type + ' message', 'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type }"
class="message-success success message" data-ui-id="message-success">
<div data-bind="html: $parent.prepareMessageForHtml(message.text)">
[MESSAGE  TEXT].
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<!-- /ko --><!-- ko if: messages().messages && messages().messages.length > 0 -->
<!-- /ko    -->
</div>
```

However when there is an error, there is just the wrapper class, so the whole HTML disappears:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
<!-- ko if: cookieMessages && cookieMessages.length > 0 -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: messages().messages && messages().messages.length > 0 -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

For me, this is rather unusual and not elegantly solved. How do I prevent the message from being vanished?

Comment: did you end up solving this?

Comment: No, it still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding the following file:
`app/design/frontend/COMPANY/THEME_NAME/Magento_Ui/web/js/view/messages.js`

and commenting out the `onHiddenChange` function at the very end.

```
           /**
             * @param {Boolean} isHidden
             */

            /*
            onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
                var self = this;
    
                // Hide message block if needed
                if (isHidden) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
           */
```

...and refresh your caches.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the file and did upgrade & content deployment & refreshed all cashes. Did not resolve the issue though.

Comment: This solution is not working

Comment: I'm still using this solution in production, it does work.

Comment: what is the magento version you using? I am having issues only for product added and removed messages on PLP/PDP

Comment: posting here if someone else having same issue as mine, I have posted my solution on this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484564/magento2-addtocart-success-msg-disappear/75945167#75945167

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem as OP.

In version 2.3.5 the fix in message.js worked.
Since the upgrade on 2.4.5 this fix is no longer in effect.

In the minicart all messages disappers within 1 second.

There is a solution linked here which includes changes to file Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js
This works, but its not exact enaugh: With this solution i must stop reloads of minicart in general, because its not possible to just stop reloading the messages.

Its just not working, nothing of the solutions. I checked any file of other modules, nothing to fix.

Any other ideas how to prevent messages in minicart to disappear so quickly?

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently in M2.4.6 p2

Just comment out the `listens` part in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js` (copy it to your theme folder)

```
defaults: {
     template: 'Magento_Ui/messages',
     selector: '[data-role=checkout-messages]',
     isHidden: false,
     hideTimeout: 5000,
     hideSpeed: 500
     /*listens: {
          isHidden: 'onHiddenChange'
     }*/
},
```

Also I'd suggest keeping the original `messages.html` template - that is keep the `visible: isVisible()` data-bind.
Otherwise the html of the messages template will always be visible and could affect the layout a little (cause of margins or similar).

After the change, you need to `redeploy static files` and `clear page cache`.

If it's still not working after these changes, then I would suggest viewing the `messages.js` file through the browser debugger to check if the changes are actually visible.

If the changes to `messsages.js` are truely visible, then most probably the error messages that are disappearing are loaded differently (possibly some theme or extension modification) and you should maybe do a text search for "messages" or "checkout-messages" in your theme folder and in all active extensions to help you find the root cause of the issue.