# Magento2 how to display (stay) messages on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, messages, transaction

In the magento2 how to handle When the credit card is declined in Magento there is a message that pops up only for a few seconds to alert sho the card has been declined. Can we make the **message stay up until** another payment method is tried?

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve (or) provide me some steps in Magento2.3.5? Example here i have attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/233259/84221, check answer given.

Comment: You can check this also https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2916#issuecomment-345343749

Comment: Thank you will check and getback to you @RahulBarot